# Pattern match for VSCode debug to cover both test and testee Jest files

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-code, debugging, jestjs

I have this configuration in `.vscode/launch.json`:

```
{
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Current Test File",
      "program": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js",
      "args": [
        "--verbose", 
        "-i", 
        "--no-cache",
        "${file}"
      ],
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen"
    }
```

This works file if focused file is `foo.spec.js`, but it doesn't if it is `foo.js`. My question is what kind of arguments should I pass to make it work for both files?

Comment: what does it mean to run Jest on a testee file instead of the file that tests it? Is this really a matter of arguments? Or is it a matter of what program you need to run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `${fileBasenameNoExtension}` instead, so for example `foo` will match both `foo.js` and `foo.spec.js`.

This is not perfect though, because it could match `foobar.js`. You just have to be careful with your naming.

Otherwise you probably cannot achieve what you want to do.

---

Here is a list of all the predefined variables you can use in a `launch.json` file:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_predefined-variables